# ID generation using AtomicLong, how to start from 0 each day

Tags: java, date, numbers, sequence

I am using `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong` class to generate sequence numbers for id generation. I need to start this number from 1 each day what are the available logic, methods which I can use?

Comment: Your title says 0, but the body of the question says 1.  (Probably not a big deal.)

Answer (score 3):

Here's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1992377/32090) on how to get the beginning of a day using Joda Time. Then use the method [AtomicLong#set(long)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html#set%28long%29) to reset the value.